# Como puxar os valores de um indice se ele possuir um determinado valor - PHP

Tags: php

Então, estou inserindo dados na SQL e precisa puxar o endereço que o cliente deixou como principal. Como eu faço para puxar os valores do indice no qual o [principal] é igual a 1?

Deve ser algo simples mas não consegui descobrir.

```
[teste] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [pais] => Brasil
                    [principal] => 1
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [pais] => Brasil
                    [principal] => 0
                )
        )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu vou assumir que queres os indices onde estão esses valores para depois aceder a esses mesmos valores, e nesse caso estarás a dar uma volta desnecessária

Podes obter os próprios valores que pretendes da seguinte maneira usando [`array_filter`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php):

```
$filt = array_filter($test, function($v) {
    return $v->principal === 1; 
});
// $filt = array_values($filt); // executar isto apenas se quiseres fazer reset às chaves
print_r($filt); // aqui veras os resultados
```

[DEMONSTRAÇÃO](https://ideone.com/JW3Rn0)

Caso queiras mesmo os indices:

```
$keys = [];
foreach($test as $k => $v) {
    if($v->principal === 1)
        $keys[] = $k;
}
print_r($keys); // aqui veras os resultados
```

[DEMONSTRAÇÃO](https://ideone.com/MhLqEZ)

Comment: Thanks for the info!